# Trying to add an "information button" to the pictures on my page that only appears when hovering

Tags: html, css, image, popup, hover

The picture I'm trying to paint is this:
I have an image of a painting in the center of my page. When I hover over the painting, I want an info icon (a small "i") to appear anchored in the top right of my image. I've placed the "i" icon simply on top of the other image. I know this is incorrect, but I don't know how to anchor it relative to the dimensions of the painting image.

Furthermore, when I hover over the "i", I want it to popup a small box with 3 lines of text (for the title of the painting, the size, and the year it was made.)

I've tried a few different methods, but none of them seem to work, so I strip the code back down to this before I try something else.

```
<div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
<img src="Placeholder.jpg" style="position: relative; top 0; left: 0;"/>
<img src="info.gif" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; right:320px"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this purely through CSS? If the info.gif was a child element of the placeholder.jpg it would work, and you could do this by swapping the img for a div or span using the background-image: url() CSS selector and then using the:

```
img[src=Placeholder.jpg]:hover {
    img[src=info.gif] {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

However, I think you're correct in using the correct image markup and you can do what you are trying to achieve with the:

```
.hover() // functionality
```

I have attached a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fxpcn4hp/) here and attached the [jQuery hover event](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) to give you a bit more background.

I have used example code with an image, and an info image showing that hovering on the picture shows the icon, and then hiding the icon when the user leaves the picture.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this without using Java?